# How to use one hot encoding for multiple label(trainy) in .fit() method?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, one-hot-encoding

I have a mobile price classification dataset in which I have 20 features and one target variable called price_range. I need to classify mobile prices as low, medium, high, very high. I have applied a one-hot encoding to my target variable. After that, I split the data into trainX, testX, trainy, testy. So my shape for trainX and trainy is (1600,20) and (1600,4) respectively.
Now when I try to fit trainX and trainy to logisticRegresion,
i.e -> lr.fit(trainX,trainy)
I am getting an error and it says: bad input (1600,4)
So, I understood that I have to give trainy value in shape (1600,1)
but by one hot encoding I have got array of 4 columns for each individual price_range as per the concept of one hot encoding.

So now I am totally confused how people use one hot encoding for target variable in practice?
please help me out.

Comment: from [OneHotEncoder documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html): *Note: a one-hot encoding of y labels should use a LabelBinarizer instead.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To train the model, you should only apply OneHotEncoder on features to gain X.
And apply LabelEncoder() to convert y.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le=preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit_transform(['a','b','a'])
```

and gain:

```
output: array([0, 1, 0])
```

Comment: So, even if I want to apply one-hot encoding to label y, I simply can not. one hot encoding is only for features and not for labels. Right?

Comment: Right. After onehotencoder, you will get one-hot matrix with dimensions (sample rows * number of features). And Labelencoder just does the job to convert 'string' label  into Int.